# Unable to insert integer when using PDO named placeholders

Tags: php, sql, pdo, placeholder

I am using named placeholders like so:

```
    $job['services_flag'] = 0;

    $SQL = "INSERT INTO jobs (
                        services_flag
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        :services_flag
                    )";

    $STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
    $STH->execute($job);
```

However, this insists on inserting `1`.

If I don't use named placeholders:

```
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO jobs (
                        services_flag
                    )
                    VALUES (
                        0
                    )";

    $STH = $DBH->prepare($SQL);
    $STH->execute();
```

Then it inserts `0`. Eh?

**Update:**
The data type of the `services_flag` field in my SQL database is `BIT`. I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, but try `$job[':services_flag'] = 0;` Note the `:` in the array key.

Comment: Just for grins, try $job['services_flag'] = 42;  Might have something to do with 0 being mistaken for null.

Comment: I put `42` and that inserts `1` (data type is `BIT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50757) with `BIT` type, you should use `bindParam` for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a value to it:

```
$STH->bindValue(':services_flag', $job['services_flag']);
$STH->execute();
```

That's one way to do it.  I've seen an array with values mapped to placeholders passed in the execute() as well.